# Error when creating container in Azure

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have installed today Azure Client Libraries using direction on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs#create-a-php-application

but i am getting below error.

400: Fail:

Code: 400

Value: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.

details (if any): InvalidHeaderValueThe value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format. RequestId:f0046f48-001e-0046-22ab-2823fb000000 Time:2017-09-08T14:06:55.1682373Zx-ms-version2012-02-12.

My Code is as below:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;

$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=MyAccountName;AccountKey=4cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==";

$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

//create container
$createContainerOptions = new CreateContainerOptions();

// private to the account owner.
$createContainerOptions->setPublicAccess(PublicAccessType::CONTAINER_AND_BLOBS);

// Set container metadata.
$createContainerOptions->addMetaData("category", "my first category data");

try    {
    // Create container.
    $blobRestProxy->createContainer("test", $createContainerOptions);
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
    // Error codes and messages are here:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179439.aspx
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo "Erro in create container <br><br>";
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
    //print_r($e);
}
```

in above code i got "Class not found" error so updated code as below:

```
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;
```

after above change in code, "class not found" error solved and also i checked that connection string is working well but getting error, which described in start of my question.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you try by commenting these two lines of code: `$createContainerOptions->setPublicAccess(PublicAccessType::CONTAINER_AND_BLOBS);` and `$createContainerOptions->addMetaData("category", "my first category data");`?

Comment: Nope :(, its not working. still same error.

Comment: What is the version of PHP SDK are you using?

Comment: PHP SDK version 0.4.2.0 as get seen in installed.json,
 "name": "microsoft/windowsazure",
        "version": "v0.4.2",
        "version_normalized": "0.4.2.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php.git",
            "reference": "b157dcac862659f0b55dc10302335bfcb9e878b5"
        },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Azure SDK Version problem so you can download SDK v0.5.5 from my this blog and also can work on your PHP 5.4

http://mytechdevelopment.blogspot.com/2018/01/azure-sdk-055-for-php-54-or-igher.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I can reproduce the error with version v.0.4.2 of [Azure SDK for PHP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php). I got problem solved by upgrading the SDK to the latest version ([v0.5.5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/releases/tag/v0.5.5))

```
{
    "require": {
        "microsoft/windowsazure": "^0.5.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think version 5.5 needs PHP >=5.6. Is this right ?